# projection and coordinate system for non georeferenced archaeological site

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, archaeology

I'm an archaeology student working on a recent project and I'm wondering how to set my arcGIS project. I'm used to work with geographical data in ArcGIS on a large scale, but the current project is different, let me explain.

I want to display and work with dispersion of artefacts on an archaeological site. This site is subdivided in 1 square meter units or parcels in which I want to display a point layer composed of each artefacts having x-y coordinates (from an arbitrary x0-y0 itself on the site). So all my coordinates make sense in the context of the site, but they are not georeferenced in any way on a geographical level.

What projection should I use to work with this kind of data, if I want my square meters units (which will be polygons) to be perfectly square without distortion (kind of a non-earth system if that's a thing).

My guess is that, on this geographical scale, distortion and error will be inexistant in any projection, but I want to make sure before starting the project in ArcGIS.